# Is there something like a "Windows Sandbox software Wrapper"?

Tags: windows, security, testing, sandbox

I am facing the current problematic: I want people to send me softwares they develop, then I want to share them to other people, in sandboxed mode, that is to say with no need to have a sandbox software...

For example, you have softwares that can manage archives, and you have auto-extracted archives.

I'd like to know if this kind of software exists: you just give it the software you want to wrap, and it gives you a sandboxed type of this soft...
Then you can share it to anybody with trust that it won't harm their computer.

Do anyone know about that on the Windows OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Molebox](http://www.molebox.com). There exist other similar solutions but I don't remember the names.

Comment: Alright, it seems to implement the functions I was searching for. If you know about equivalent solutions in the open source world, please let me know. Thanks again